# How do you set up CC.Net as a service?

Tags: .net, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net

I am trying to set up Cruise Control so that it runs as a service.  How is this done?  Also what difficulties as far as rights go might I run into?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check out the [official documentation](http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/The+Server+Service+Application) on this. That said, I have done it in the past without having to muck about with anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: the link points to CruiseControl doc. This is the link to CruiseControl.NET doc: http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/The+Server+Service+Application

Comment: and yet it was accepted as the answer, so I'm guessing it answered the question, or he did not actually test it.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I fixed the link now. Thanks Chairman.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to use CC.Net but I found myself spending more time to keep things running smoothly on builds than coding... I switched to [TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) since it's free for small to medium projects.

Answer (score 0):

In the installation folder of CC.NET you will fine two executables viz. **ccnet.exe** and **ccnetservice.exe**. The former one is the console mode host and the later a windows service. You can start/stop that service from the windows service controller panel. (Start->Run->Services.msc). Please make sure both the exes have the same contents in the config file.

James